# Determine the resultant for the vector sum: 10N at 045° and then 8 N at 068°?

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

So if you draw it out on a quadrant the angle between 10N and 8N should be

68 - 45 = 23° right?

So can i do cosine law to solve the resultant?

c^2 = 10^2 + 8^2 - 2(10)(8)cos 23
c = 4.09

is this wrong?

how do i find the direction of the resultant?

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong angle.  We have $AB=10, BC=8 \angle CAB=\angle DBE23^\circ$    To get the resultant you want $AD$, so the angle to use in the cosine law is $\angle ABD$

To the resultant, I would put $A$ at the origin and calculate the vectors $AB, AC$, then add them.

Added:  One way is to calculate the vectors.  Assuming three place accuracy is acceptable, $10$N at $45^\circ$ is $(7.07,7.07)$N and $8$N at $68^\circ$ is $(8\cos 68^\circ, 8\sin 68^\circ)N=(3.00,7.42)$N, so the resultant is $(10.07,14.49)N$ with an angle of $\arctan(\frac {14.49}{10.07})=55.20^\circ$  The other way to get the resultant is the cosine law:  $AD^2=AB^2+BD^2-2AB\cdot BD \cos \theta$.  As $\angle DBE=23^\circ, \angle ABD=157^\circ$, so $AC^2=164-160\cdot (-0.921), AC=17.643$  There are rounding errors.

[image]

Comment: but isnt BC at 68 degrees? and isn't AB at 45 degrees? why did you draw it like this?

Comment: If A is the origin, AB is close to 45 degrees.  Then AC is at 68 degrees.  If you are looking for the resultant, you add them as vectors, making a parallelogram.

Comment: exactly so if CB is my resultant, then isn't solving for angle A going to give me the resultant?

Comment: using cosine law?

Comment: and doesnt AC = 10 AND AB = 8?

Comment: Yes, I made a better figure.  Take a look

Comment: oh so we need to use the parallelogram method?

Comment: I think that is the easier way. You can use the cosine and sine laws if you get the correct angle.

Comment: Sorry this is so late but would angle ABD = 157 degrees? everytime i use cosine law to solve for the resultant i keep getting 15.47 N :( the correct answer is 17.6 N at 055 degrees

Comment: assuming the resultant is AD

Comment: @RossMikkikan could you help me please?

Comment: WOW THANK YOU SO MUCH ACTUALLY I FINALLY UNDERSTAND IT OMG THANK YOU (I HATE CALCULUS SO MUCH) but honestly i really appreciate this thank you so much and have an great night!

Comment: I didn't put the "2" in the cosine law omggggg i'm the biggest idiot omg